# O que, exatamente, há dentro do objeto "arquivo"?

Tags: c++, arquivo

A partir do meu código executei o seguinte teste:

```cpp
  ofstream arquivo;
  arquivo.open("desempenho.txt", ios::app);
```

Gostaria de saber o seguinte: O que exatamente há dentro da variável '`arquivo`' quando executo o comando '`arquivo.open()`'?

Uma explicação objetiva e um link confiável de referência são apreciados.

Answer (score 0):

A implementação de `std::ofstream` possui, internamente, o estado de abertura para leitura ou escrita de um arquivo.

Objetos do tipo `std::ofstream` mantém uma instância de um [filebuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/filebuf/) dentro deles como um estado interno. Ao chamar `std::ofstream::open`, o objeto mencionado abrirá o arquivo e continuará servindo de estado interno para leitura ou escrita (escrita no caso abaixo ao chamar o operador `<<`):

```
  std::ofstream arquivo;
  arquivo.open("desempenho.txt", std::ios::app);
  arquivo << "Inserindo conteúdo ao final do arquivo\n";
```

Os sites [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) e [cplusplus](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/) têm exemplos e algumas explicações sobre suas implementações, também sobre o método [open](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/).